# How to draw rounded corners with QPainter::drawPolyLine

Tags: qt, qpainter

I'm trying to create a custom container widget at the moment using QGroupBox as a base and drawing the new frame in the paint event, which is all working fine using drawPolyLine to create it, but I'd like to draw the frame with rounded corners. Has anyone come across a way to do it with drawPolyLine or would I need to rewrite my code to implement them?

Comment: `void QPainter::drawRoundedRect(const QRectF& rect, qreal xRadius, qreal yRadius, Qt::SizeMode mode)`?

Comment: It's not a complete rectangle, imagine a binder divider for the shape.

Comment: As it's irregular, you can create complex shapes from simple ones by 'layering' them on top of each other using `QPainterPath`.

Comment: You should be able to do this by setting a QPen with the appropriate joinStyle().

Comment: @cbamber85: that's one of the options, it just means swapping QPen's to 'erase' the top section.

Comment: @DanMilburn: I thought that, but it keeps it as a square corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to custom flexible shapes, [QPainterPath](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qpainterpath.html) is the most powerful class of them all. You could for example use [QPainterPath::arcTo()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qpainterpath.html#arcTo) in order to draw single rounded corners, though painting the full shape might require some math.

Another possibility is defining single shapes and merging them using `intersected()` or `subtracted()`, as already suggested by cbamber85 in the comments.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen the intersected method, that might do quite nicely. I was hoping I could get the rounded corners free of charge but I'll just work around it!

Answer (score 4):

QPen has a "Cap Style" option of Qt::RoundCap which could result in rounded corners depending on pen width.